# Basic Karma Angular 1.5 Component Test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am not sure if what I am doing is completely wrong, but when I switched from "directive" to "components" for defining a few of my HTML elements, I suddenly broke all of my Karma tests.  here's what I have:

**karam.conf.js**

```
...
preprocessors: {
    'module-a/module-a.view.html': ['ng-html2js'],
    ...,
    'module-z/module-z.view.html': ['ng-html2js']
},

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    moduleName: 'theTemplates'
},
...
```

**module-a.component.js**

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    angular.module('ModuleA').component('moduleAComponent',{
        controller: 'ModuleAController as moduleAVm',
        templateUrl: 'module-a/module-a.view.html'      
    });
})();
```

**module-a-tests.js**

```
"use strict";

describe('ModuleA',function(){

    beforeEach(module('ModuleA'));

    describe('Controller',function(){
        ...
    });

    describe('Component',function(){
        var element, $rootScope;
        beforeEach(module('theTemplates'));
        beforeEach(inject([
            '$compile','$rootScope',
            function($c,$rs) {
               $rootScope = $rs;
               element = $c('<module-a-component></module-a-component>')($rootScope);
               $rootScope.$digest(); // ???
            }
        ]));

        it('should have moduleAVm',function(){
            expect(element.html()).not.toBe(''); // FAILS HERE
            expect(element.html()).toContain('moduleVm'); // FAILS HERE TOO
        });

    });

});
```

**The Error:**

```
Expected '' not to be ''.
```

Comment: can u add the error what you are seeing on console ? Also try with this angular.module('ModuleA',[]).component('moduleAComponent'....

Comment: I defined `angular.module('ModuleA',[])` in `module-a/module-a.module.js`, so I believe that is fine.  However, I added the error.  It's failing on the expect call which means element.html() is empty, which means it's not digesting (I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, after reading Angular's [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) more thoroughly, I came across this statement:

> The easiest way to unit-test a component controller is by using the
>   $componentController that is included in ngMock. The advantage of this
>   method is that you do not have to create any DOM elements. The
>   following example shows how to do this for the heroDetail component
>   from above.

And it dawned on me, my describe('Controller',function(){...}); was what I really needed to change, and that I should just get rid of the 'Component' portion, formally known as 'Directive'

Here's my 'Controller' now:

```
    beforeEach(inject([
        '$componentController', // replaced $controller with $componentController
        function($ctrl){
            ctrl = $ctrl('queryResults',{ // Use component name, instead of controller name
                SomeFactory:MockSomeFactory,
                SomeService:MockSomeService
            });
        }
    ]));
```

Now, I still get to test my controller, while simultaneously testing the component.  And I no longer have to create DOM elements using $compile, $rootScope, etc.

Comment: can we say, that you need not create element at all when you can use `$componentController`?